# Use a personal program in Firebreath

Tags: c++, firebreath

I'm building a plugin using Firebreath. I made a personal method in `ABCPluginAPI.cpp` called `exe_program()` and I would like to call another program using popen called `my_program`. All the files are into firebreath/projects/ABCPlugin/.

My method is:

```
string ABCPluginAPI::exe_program()
{
    FILE * pPipe;
    fd_set readfd;
    char buff[1024];
    char command[128];
    int ret;

    strcpy(command, "my_program");

    if (!(pPipe = popen(command, "r"))) {
         // Problem to execute the command
       return "failed";
    }
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), pPipe)!=NULL){
        cout << buff;
        return buff;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the plugin is not running `my_program`, actually if I execute the `pwd` command, it shows my $HOME directory. `pwd` works because is a general command but I don't want to put my program into $PATH variable because this plugin must be portable.

Probably Firebreath use a special directory to refer to this kind of files or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to specify a full path and filename of the application you want to run; the current working directory is not garanteed to always be the same value.

From the [Tips and Tricks](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Tips+and+Tricks#TipsandTricks-GettingthepathandfilenameofthepluginDLLsoordylib) page of firebreath.org there is code you can add to your PluginCore-derived object that will give you the full path and filename of your plugin file:

```
// From inside your Plugin class (that extends PluginCore)
std::string MyPlugin::getFilesystemPath()
{
    return m_filesystemPath;
}
```

You can take that path, strip off the last part, and change it to your executable filename; as long as you place the executable in the same directory as your plugin that should work fine.  Alternately you could install it in some other well-known location.

Note that to call a method on your main Plugin object from your JSAPI object there should be a helper method getPlugin() on your JSAPI object (if you used fbgen to generate it):

```
std::string pluginPath = getPlugin()->getFilesystemPath();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: The pluginPath showed me: `$HOME/Documents/firebreath/build/bin/ABCPlugin`, i put my executable file in there and call it, but didn't work. Actually i try with pwd executable in that folder as well, but it didn't work. I called with ./pwd, and with the absolute path $HOME/Documents/firebreath/build/bin/ABCPlugin/pwd. Thanks for your help taxilian.

Comment: try launching firefox from a console window and/or with the -g option (to put it in the debugger); in a console and definitely w/ -g you should get stdout output, so you may be able to spot an error message

Comment: Well, i had i little confusion between the path, but got it working after all. Thank you for your help.